# Joomla: get items modified on setState method

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

I have a component on two websites.

When an user insert, update or delete an item in the first website, the same action must be performed on the second website. I made that using the `postSaveHook()` method: when an action is performed in the first site, I connect to the database of the second site and replicate the action.

I need to do the same thing when an user changes the items' state: if he/she unpublishes two items, for example, the items must be unpublished in the second site. I tried to change the `setState()` method to do that, but inside this method I couldn't get any referente to the items changed.

Does anybody know another solution or how to do that with `setState()`?

**P.S.** Sorry about my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution: override the method `public function publish(&$pks, $value = 1)` of the class `JModelAdmin`. In this method I have all the primary keys of the items changed. Then I was able to get their states and update the items on the second site.